# Describe all the possible images of $f$ such that $f\colon D_{10}\to H$ is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $H$ be a group and suppose that $f\colon D_{10} \to H$ is a homomorphism. Describe all the possible images of $f$.

I know by definition, $\operatorname{Im} (f) = \{h \in H \mid h=f(g) \text{ for some } g \in G\}$ and I have all the elements of $D_{10}$ but I have no idea how to start to answer the question. I hope you can help me.

Comment: *Hint*: Use the [First Isomorphism Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem) and your knowledge of the subgroups of $D_{10}$.

Comment: By 1st isomorphism theorem, I know that G/Ker(f) =~ Im (f) so that means I now have to compute Ker(f) right? Then, by definition i know that Ker (f)= {g in G such that f(g)=identity element in H}. How do I know what function f is so that I can apply to g to find the identity?sorry I'm just so clueless about this.

Comment: The kernel of a homomorphism is always a normal subgroup.  What are the normal subgroups of $D_{10}$?

Comment: The normal subgroups of D10 are the identity, D10 and <sigma>

Comment: Then those are the only possible kernels. What, then, are the possible images?

Comment: Is it the set of D10/{e} , D10/D10 and D10/<sigma> ?

Comment: @wanhikmah: Ya! The possible cases are as you noted. What is sigma in your definition?

Comment: Alright. Just want to make sure of this, is it that when D10/{e} =~ D10 and D10/D10={e}? My sigma is (12345)

Comment: @wanhikmah: $D_{10}/e_{D_{10}}\cong D_{10}$ and another second structure is $D_{10}$.

Comment: How do it then when D10/<sigma>?